# Get JSON url from textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My script is to get JSON file from url entered in textbox

I IDed textbox as `txtr` and use jquery to get value `var txtbval = $("#txtr").val();` and this in json parsing script `url: txtbval,`

But when I clicked on button nothing happen I don't know what I did wrong and I'm not sure that this method can be used in JSON Parsing

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>How to Parse a JSON file using jQuery</title>

    <style>
        body{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: arial;
        }

        .button{
            margin:20px;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding:5px 10px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <textarea id=txtr" rows="4" cols="50">
    </textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Get and parse JSON" class="button" />
    <br />
    <span id="results"></span>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        //When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var txtbval = $("#txtr").val();
            //after button is clicked we download the data
            $('.button').click(function(){

                //start ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    url: txtbval,
                    //force to handle it as text
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {

                        //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
                        //and pass downloaded data
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        //now json variable contains data in json format
                        //let's display a few items
                        $('#results').html(json.post.title);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: comment datatype option of ajax for a while and directly check, data.post.title

Comment: When you know you will get JSON in response then why you are doing this JSON parsing? simply set `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your html missing `"` in begning of id in textarea: change

```
<textarea id=txtr" rows="4" cols="50">
    </textarea>
```

To

```
<textarea id="txtr" rows="4" cols="50">
    </textarea>
```

and it should work fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
          
            //after button is clicked we download the data
            $('.button').click(function(){
               var txtbval = $("#txtr").val();
               console.log("url:"+$("#txtr").val());
                //start ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    url: txtbval,
                    //force to handle it as text
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        $('#results').html(json.post.title);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtr" rows="4" cols="50">
    </textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Get and parse JSON" class="button" />
    <br />
    <span id="results"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks! and I wanna know that why I can't use this script in local? I need to run this on my website

Comment: @TacticalBacon it should work fine as long as you are passing proper url of the file.

Comment: And how I add prefix and suffix to entered value from textbox? Like I enter 4786 and It leads to www.example.com/?p=4786&=json1 (enter only post id but still lead to json file)

Comment: @TacticalBacon like ` var txtbval = prefix+"/"+$("#txtr").val()+"?p=4786&json1=json1;`.here prefix is the value you want to append before. like `www.google.com`.

Comment: Uhh I used `var txtbval = "www.sd.ac.th/main/?p="+$("#txtr").val()+"&json=1";` but it's return as `GET http://www.sd.ac.th/main/wp-content/2017/1/www.sd.ac.th/main/?p=8722&json=1 404 (Not Found)` How to link from root url? (http://www.sd.ac.th/main/wp-content/2017/1/ is where my script files are)

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you are missing:

1) First of all you were missing **(")** in your **id="txtr"**

2) You need to get the value of the **textarea** after clicking the button.

Since I don't know what API you are using I used this API:

> http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments

and got the value of the name from first JSON object.

**Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!**

```js
//When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //after button is clicked we download the data
        $('.button').click(function(){
            var txtbval = $("textarea#txtr").val();

            //start ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: txtbval,
                //force to handle it as text
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                    //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function
                    //and pass downloaded data
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    //now json variable contains data in json format
                    //let's display a few items
                    $('#results').html(json[0].name);
                },
                error : function (error) {
                    alert("Enter API");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
 body{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: arial;
        }

        .button{
            margin:20px;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding:5px 10px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtr" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Get and parse JSON" class="button" />
<br />
<span id="results"></span>
```